# Reuse the same thread function for several independent data structures

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

First, Im sorry for not good at English. I have learned C language, and new to Python.Now Im using Python to write a little thing, and reached to a confusing question:
I`m trying to start three threads using the same thread function for three axis called x, y and z,each thread should have an independent data structure(including a queue, a condition var and a flag).I will change condition var and flag to sync another thread.

I have wrote the thread function as follow:

```
def thread_axis(self, axis: str, q: queue.Queue, cond: threading.Condition, cond_flag: bool):
        axis_name = axis.strip().upper()
        line = q.get()
        if type(line) == str:
            print(line)
        else:
            self.error_log(1, "type_err")

        with self.data_lock:
            cond_flag = True
            cond.notify()
```

(Yes, a class method)

But obviously, `the cond_flag` and `cond` won`t change.I searched for internet and realize that Python can`t change most of the var in function.And the good practice to change the outer var is seems to use the return value, like this:

```
def swap(a, b):
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
    return a, b
```

and use like this:

```
x = 10
y = 20
x, y = swap(x, y)
print(x, y)
```

But this practice is obviously can`t use as changing a outer variable in thread. Is there a feature in Python that can change a variable in a function like pointer in C?
Or did I just went wrong in all of this?